# Как добавить рамку с закруглениями и заменить крест на галочку в QcheckBox

Tags: qt

Нужно использовать QcheckBox. У меня в качестве интерфейса ввода используется тачскрин. И использование стандартного QcheckBox не возможна из-за малого размера. Охота сделать больше. И когда нажимаешь на QcheckBox в центре появляется крест, а охота галочку.

Смог только изменить размер:

```
QCheckBox::indicator
{
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
};
```

А как добавить рамку и галочку вместо крестика не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через CSS ([StyleSheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html))

```
QCheckBox{ 
    border: 1px solid black
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked {
    image: url(:/images/your_image.png);
}
```